# 21" Screencasting

Tags: macos, screen-capture, youtube, recording

I started screen-casting for YouTube but stumbled upon a dilemma.

When viewing one of my videos on YouTube, the text is impossible to read because my monitor is too big. Of course there's the option of full-screen HD, but only some users like that.

My question is, how can I record for YouTube at the best possible quality without having to go into full-screen mode?

Thanks for your help in advance,
Mikey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lower your screen resolution by going to System Preferences > Displays